# QuickSort Program Not Outputting Right

Tags: java, javascript, quicksort

I am attempting to make a QuickSort program and while I feel like it should be outputting as desired, it is not. I feel the problems lies in how I have constructed my loops but that may not be the case. As you can see, the first test with the runner prints out as I want and everything eventually gets sorted right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

My main program:

```js
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Arrays;  
 //use Arrays.toString() to help print out the array

public class QuickSort
{
 private static int passCount;

 public static void quickSort(Comparable[] list)
 {
  passCount=0;
  quickSort(list, 0, list.length-1);
 }


 private static void quickSort(Comparable[] list, int low, int high)
 {
  if(low >= high) 
   return;

  int a = partition(list, low, high);
  quickSort(list, low, a-1);
  quickSort(list, a+1, high);
 }


 private static int partition(Comparable[] list, int low, int high)
 {
  int x = low + 1;
        int y = high;

        while(x <= y) 
         {
            if(list[x].compareTo(list[low]) <= 0) 
             {x++;}
            
            else if(list[y].compareTo(list[low]) > 0) 
             {y--;}
            
            else if(y < x) 
             {break;}
             
            else
                exchange(list, x, y);
            }
            
            exchange(list, low, y);
   
   out.println("pass " + passCount++ + " " + Arrays.toString(list) + "\n");
            return y;
            
        }

        private static void exchange(Object[] list, int x, int y) {
            Object temporary = list[x];
            list[x] = list[y];
            list[y] = temporary;
        }
}
```

My runner:

```js
public class QuickSortRunner
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  QuickSort.quickSort(new Comparable[]{9,5,3,2});
  System.out.println("\n");

  QuickSort.quickSort(new Comparable[]{19,52,3,2,7,21});
  System.out.println("\n");

  QuickSort.quickSort(new Comparable[]{68,66,11,2,42,31});
  System.out.println("\n");
 }
}
```

My output:

```js
pass 0 [2, 5, 3, 9]

pass 1 [2, 5, 3, 9]

pass 2 [2, 3, 5, 9]


pass 0 [2, 7, 3, 19, 52, 21]

pass 1 [2, 7, 3, 19, 52, 21]

pass 2 [2, 3, 7, 19, 52, 21]

pass 3 [2, 3, 7, 19, 21, 52]


pass 0 [31, 66, 11, 2, 42, 68]

pass 1 [11, 2, 31, 66, 42, 68]

pass 2 [2, 11, 31, 66, 42, 68]

pass 3 [2, 11, 31, 42, 66, 68]
```

Desired output:

```js
pass 0 [2, 5, 3, 9]

pass 1 [2, 5, 3, 9]

pass 2 [2, 3, 5, 9]


pass 0 [7, 2, 3, 52, 19, 21]

pass 1 [3, 2, 7, 52, 19, 21]

pass 2 [2, 3, 7, 52, 19, 21]

pass 3 [2, 3, 7, 21, 19, 52]

pass 4 [2, 3, 7, 19, 21, 52]


pass 0 [31, 66, 11, 2, 42, 68]

pass 1 [2, 11, 66, 31, 42, 68]

pass 2 [2, 11, 66, 31, 42, 68]

pass 3 [2, 11, 42, 31, 66, 68]

pass 4 [2, 11, 31, 42, 66, 68]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `x++` and `y--` to skip exchanges need to be in `while` loops so that exchange happens only when it is called for.

Comment: Are you saying I just strictly change **if**(list[x].compareTo(list[low]) <= 0 {x++;} && **else if**(list[y].compareTo(list[low]) > 0) {y--;} to then read **while**(list[x].compareTo(list[low]) <= 0 {x++;} && **while**(list[y].compareTo(list[low]) > 0) {y--;} ? I don't need to change where my print line is?

Comment: well the while loops also need to test that you haven't crossed the streams (x < y), otherwise you will get index out of bounds exceptions. but I was just telling you the first thing that is wrong with the code, not a complete diff to a working version. fix that and resume debugging.